# Split function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have `Table1` with columns like this:

```
+--+------+
|ID|Name  |
+--+------+
|1 |MSSQL |
+--+------+
|2 |MySQl |
+--+------+
|3 |Oracle|
+--+------+
```

In `Table2`, I have a column like

```
+------------+
|Databasename|
+------------+
|1,3         |
+------------+
|2           |
+------------+
|1,2         |
+------------+
```

My output should be:

```
+------------+
|Databasename|
+------------+
|MSSQL,Oracle|
+------------+
|MySQL       |
+------------+
|MSSQL,MYSQL |
+------------+
```

How do I get this, I need query for this..

Comment: Storing comma delimited lists in the database is not a good practice. The query for this will be pretty horrible.

Comment: Search for `Split Function in SQL` you will get plenty.

Comment: Why do people keep doing this? It's as basic an error as using surname as a unique key.

Answer (score 6):

First, your best solution is to not store data in a comma-separated list in your database. You should consider fixing the table structure.

If you cannot alter the table structure, then you will need to split the data in the list to rows to assign the correct name.  Once the data is split then you can concatenate the data back into the list.

There are many different `split` function that you can find online but here is a version that I typically use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

To get your result, I would start by applying the `split` function and a `row_number()` since I do not see a unique key associated with each row. If you have a unique key on each row then you will not need the `row_number()`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select rn, name, id
  from
  (
    select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn,
      databasename
    from table2
  ) t2
  cross apply dbo.split(t2.databasename, ',') i
  inner join table1 t1
    on i.items = t1.id
) 
select *
from cte
```

This query breaks your comma-separated list into the following:

```
| RN |   NAME | ID |
--------------------
|  1 |  MSSQL |  1 |
|  1 | Oracle |  3 |
|  2 |  MySQl |  2 |
|  3 |  MSSQL |  1 |
|  3 |  MySQl |  2 |
```

Once you have the data in multiple rows with the correct `name`, then you can use `STUFF()` and `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate it into the list. You full query would be similar to this:

```
;with cte as
(
  select rn, name, id
  from
  (
    select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) rn,
      databasename
    from table2
  ) t2
  cross apply dbo.split(t2.databasename, ',') i
  inner join table1 t1
    on i.items = t1.id
) 
select  
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + c2.name
          FROM cte c2
          where c1.rn = c2.rn
          order by c2.id
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '') Databasename
from cte c1
group by c1.rn
order by c1.rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0113/15).

The result of the full query is:

```
|   DATABASENAME |
------------------
|  MSSQL, Oracle |
|          MySQl |
|   MSSQL, MySQl |
```

Answer (score 6):

You are asking for a split function but you do not have to split your values to get the result you want.

This query builds the comma separated names list in a correlated subquery using the `for xml` trick to concatenate values. It uses `like` to figure out what values to use from `Table1` for each row in `Table2`.

```
select (
       select ', '+T1.Name
       from Table1 as T1
       where ','+T2.Databasename+',' like '%,'+cast(T1.ID as varchar(10))+',%'
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as Databasenames
from Table2 as T2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c6a1/1)

Answer (score 0):

No splitting, also no XML Path, but achieves the right result.

```
;with cte as (
    select *, cast(null as varchar(1024)) as str, cast(0 as int) as ID
    from Table2

    union all

    select DatabaseName, (case when DatabaseName like cast(t.ID as varchar(32)) + ',%' 
                                    or DatabaseName like '%,' + cast(t.ID as varchar(32)) + ',%'
                                    or DatabaseName like '%,' + cast(t.ID as varchar(32)) 
                                    or DatabaseName = cast(t.ID as varchar(32)) then cast(isnull(str, '') + ',' + t.Name as varchar(1024)) else str end), cte.ID + 1 as ID
    from cte
    inner join Table1 t on cte.ID + 1 = t.ID
)
select DatabaseName, (case when str like ',%' then substring(str, 2, len(str)) else null end) as str
from cte c
where ID = (select max(ID) from cte where DatabaseName = c.DatabaseName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Here it goes:

----------------
-- FieldCount --
----------------
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FieldCount](@S VARCHAR(8000), @Separator VARCHAR(10))
  RETURNS INT
AS

BEGIN

  /*
  @Author: Leonardo Augusto Rezende Santos
  @Contact: http://www.linkedin.com/pub/leonardo-santos/0/2b1/890
  */

  DECLARE @Ptr INT, @p INT, @LenS INT, @LenSep INT, @Result INT

  IF @Separator = ' ' 
    BEGIN
      SET @S = REPLACE(@S, ' ', '|-|')
      SET @Separator = '|-|'
    END

  WHILE CHARINDEX(@Separator + @Separator, @S) > 0
    SET @S = Replace(@S, @Separator + @Separator, @Separator + '_-_' + @Separator)
  IF @S <> ''
    SET @Result = 1
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @Result = 0
      RETURN(@Result)
    END
  SET @Ptr = 0
  SET @LenS = LEN(@S)
  SET @LenSep = LEN(@Separator)
  SET @p = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @S)
  WHILE @p > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @Result = @Result + 1
      SET @Ptr = @Ptr + @p + @LenSep
      SET @p = CHARINDEX(@Separator, SUBSTRING(@S, @Ptr, @LenS - @Ptr + 1))
    END

  RETURN(@Result)

END

--------------
-- GetField --
--------------
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetField](@S VARCHAR(8000), @Separator VARCHAR(10), @Field INT)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS

BEGIN

  /*
  @Author: Leonardo Augusto Rezende Santos
  @Contact: http://www.linkedin.com/pub/leonardo-santos/0/2b1/890
  */

  DECLARE @Ptr INT, @p INT, @LenS INT, @LenSep INT, @Fld INT, @Result VARCHAR(8000)

  IF @Separator = ' ' 
    BEGIN
      SET @S = REPLACE(@S, ' ', '|-|')
      SET @Separator = '|-|'
    END

  IF @Field > dbo.FieldCount(@S, @Separator)
    BEGIN
      SET @Result = ''
      RETURN(@Result)
    END
  SET @Fld = 1
  SET @Ptr = 1
  SET @LenS = LEN(@S)
  SET @LenSep = LEN(@Separator)
  SET @p = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @S)
  WHILE (@p > 0) and (@Fld < @Field)
    BEGIN
      SET @Fld = @Fld + 1
      SET @Ptr = @Ptr + @p + @LenSep - 1
      SET @p = CHARINDEX(@Separator, SUBSTRING(@S, @Ptr, @LenS - @Ptr + 1))
    END
  IF (@p = 0) and (@Fld = @Field)
    SET @p = @LenS - @Ptr + 2
  SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@S, @Ptr, @p - 1)

  RETURN(@Result)

END

/* USAGE*/

select dbo.FieldCount('A1 A2 A3 A4 A5', ' ')

--It will return 5

select dbo.GetField('A1 A2 A3 A4 A5', ' ', 3)

--It will return 'A3'

select dbo.GetField('A1/A2/A3/A4/A5', '/', 3)

--It will return 'A3'

--Hope it works for you.

--Leonardo Augusto
```