# split up sql column into queryable results set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is my issue:

I have a column with the following data in an sql column:

```
Answers
=======
1:2:5: <--- notice my delimiter
```

I need to be able to break up the digits into a result set that i can join against a lookup  table such as

```
Answers_Expanded
=======
1 apple
2 pear
3 cherry
4 mango
5 grape
```

and return

```
Answers
=======
apple pear grape
```

Any such way?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe PIVOT ? have a look at this article, it will probably help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You Can do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911167/split-function-in-sql-server-2008/14918846#14918846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack (the `LIKE`, the `XML PATH`, and the `STUFF`), and it assumes that you want the answers ordered by their `ID` as opposed to matching up with the original order in the multivalued column...

But this gives the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT STUFF((
  SELECT ' ' + ae.Answer
  FROM
    Answers_Expanded ae
    JOIN Answers a ON ':' + a.Answers LIKE '%:' + CAST(ae.ID AS VARCHAR) + ':%' 
  ORDER BY ae.ID
  FOR XML PATH(''))
, 1, 1, '') AS Answers
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb88d/16)

This works because:

1. Joining with `LIKE` finds any `Answer_Expanded` rows that match the multivalued column.
2. `XML PATH` simulates a group concatenation... and allows for `' '` to be specified as the delimiter
3. `STUFF` removes the leading delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) has a good example of a user defined function that will return a table with the values from your delimited string in a column.  You can then join that table to your Answers_Expanded table to get your value.

This works fine if you are parsing reasonably short strings, and if you are doing it as a one time thing, but if you have a table with your answers stored in a column like that, you don't want to be running this on the whole table as it will be a large performance hit.  Ideally you'd want to avoid getting delimited strings like this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest that you save your answers in a way that one cell has only one number...not multible information in one cell. (violation of the 1st normal form).

otherwise you better use some higher sql language such as T-SQL.