# sql stored procedure convert code to text in string with a raw of codes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a string with codes that seperated with a commas,

example:

```
@inputText = "1,2,3,4,5"
```

and i need a convert to:

```
@outputText = "apple, peach, orange, banana, onion"
```

i have codes table:

```
id name
-- ----
1  apple
2  peach
3  orange
4  banana
5  onion
```

i am using sql server 2008

i need the stored procedure code that doing it, thanks.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, SQL*Server, Postgresql? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i edited the question and added sql server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` along with `LIKE` to replace the values in the comma separated list:

```
declare @text varchar(50) = '1,2,3,4,5'

;with cte as 
(
    select @text list
) 
select 
(
    select ', '+c.name
    from codes c
    where ','+t1.list+',' like '%,'+cast(c.ID as varchar(10))+',%'
    for xml path(''), type
).value('substring(text()[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as NewList
from cte t1
```

This is based on an answer by [@Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911167/split-function-in-sql-server-2008/14918846#14918846)