# How to use a set of strings in a WHERE statement of SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

Sorry i am not sure how to titled the question well. I want to select few records in sql where a particular column is a set of strings.

Example . I have a table student and has columns ID and name. ID has records 1,2,3,4,5,6 . NAme has A,B,C,D,E,F.

I want to return C,D,E WHERE ID=[3,4,5].

I tried

```
SELECT FROM student WHERE ID=2,3,4
```

it gives error, ID`=2,3,4 ='2,3,4'` and it reads ID as a single columns. I am confused.

Also in my case, ID set are returned in a storedprocedure variable. that is like @ID

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ID=@ID
```

@ID above is a variable of a string type holding the set {1,2,3}. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE ID=[3,4,5]` That's not valid syntax. You want `WHERE ID IN (3, 4, 5)`, and unfortunately you cannot add a single parameter containing the set of legal values there. Your best option is to either construct the SQL dynamically, or insert the values into a temporary table and do a join (or sub-select in the IN-clause).

Comment: Try `SELECT FROM student WHERE ID IN (2,3,4)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE ID IN (2,3,4)
```

Syntax:

```
test_expression IN 
    ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ]
    )
```

Read more about IN operator [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE ID=2,3,4`  and  `WHERE ID='2,3,4'` are invalid syntax for SQL.

Looks like you can use [`IN (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) on your situation.

> Determines whether a specified value matches any value in a subquery
>   or a list.

```
SELECT FROM student WHERE ID IN (2, 3, 4)
```

Also you might take a look Jeff's question [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 3):

If you are passing `@ID` as a variable with comma separated list of ids, `WHERE IN (@ID)` will not work.

I think best thing would be to use a `Table Valued function` to split them first and then query the table. Please check here for a **[Split() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911167/split-function-in-sql-server-2008)**.

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT 
WHERE ID IN (
              SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@ID, ',') --Split function here
            )
```

Comment: It is a simple one what is the use of Functions here Please check this out "Select Username from Student where ID IN ' + '('+ @Id +')'"
 where @Id=2,3,4 we can use like this

Comment: @Anjali: OP is using a stored procedure and not passing inline sql so It won't work unless you run a dynamic query.

Comment: Ok, but it work for stored procedures also i am using that query in stored procedures

Comment: Can you help me based on this. please come to chat

Comment: @Anjali: sure no problem, you can invite me.

Comment: i don't know how to Invite to chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39629/discussion-between-kaf-and-anjali)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fitler multiple values in Select, you should use "in ()":

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE ID in (2,3,4)
OR
SELECT * FROM student WHERE ID between 2 and 4
OR
SELECT * FROM student WHERE ID = 2  OR ID = 3 OR ID = 4
```

In this case take the first one. 
The last one is very slow and not recommended in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment below, you don't want to convert `ID` to an int. Instead, use `LIKE` to compare:

```
SELECT * from STUDENT
WHERE ', '+@ID+', ' LIKE ', '+CAST(ID as NVARCHAR(255)) + ', ';
```

However, the query will not be indexed. If you want the query to be indexed, then use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ID IN ('+ @ID +')';
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: i understand the solution given should resolve my question
but my ID column is of bigINT datatype
and my `@id` variable is returned as string like {1,2,3}
when i try conactenating the two
i mean like SELECT * FROM students where ID IN @ID
i get error because column ID is of BIGINT
and i can't convert `@ID` to INT
pls how do i go about this?
You there?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this out

```
Select * from Student where Id IN ('2','3','4')
```

and check this out

```
Select Username from Student where ID IN ' + '('+ @Id +')'
 where @Id=2,3,4
```

Comment: i understand the solution given should resolve my question but my ID column is of bigINT datatype and my `@id` variable is returned as string like {1,2,3} when i try concatenating the two i mean like SELECT * FROM students where ID IN @ID i get error because column ID is of BIGINT and i can't convert `@ID` to INT pls how do i go about this? You there?

Answer (score 2):

**Since you are using Stored Procedure**, that also has only equality compare i.e. id = 1, so either you have too execute three queries by splitting the input by comma separated values.

**OR** you can add a new procedure with a custom function to server with the SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myparameter_to_list (@parameter VARCHAR(500)) returns @myOutput TABLE (mytempVal VARCHAR(40))
AS  
begin
     DECLARE @TempTable table
          (
          mytempVal VARCHAR(40)
          )

     DECLARE @MySplittedValue varchar(40), @PositionOfComma int

     SET @par = LTRIM(RTRIM(@parameter))+ ','
     SET @PositionOfComma = CHARINDEX(',', @parameter, 1)

     IF REPLACE(@parameter, ',', '') <> ''
     BEGIN
          WHILE @PositionOfComma > 0
          BEGIN
               SET @MySplittedValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@par, @PositionOfComma - 1)))
               IF @MySplittedValue <> ''
               BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @TempTable (mytempVal) VALUES (@MySplittedValue) --Use conversion if needed
               END
               SET @par = RIGHT(@par, LEN(@par) - @PositionOfComma)
               SET @PositionOfComma = CHARINDEX(',', @par, 1)

          END
     END    
     INSERT @myOutput
     SELECT mytempVal 
        FROM @TempTable
     RETURN
END
```

In your stored procedure you would use it like this:

```
Create Procedure StudentSelectFromSet 
@Ids VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
SELECT * FROM student Stud
WHERE Stud.Id IN(SELECT value FROM dbo.myparameter_to_list (@Ids))
```

and then execute this new procedure as you were accessing earlier.

Comment: i understand the solution given should resolve my question but my ID column is of bigINT datatype and my `@id` variable is returned as string like {1,2,3} when i try concatenating the two i mean like SELECT * FROM students where ID IN @ID i get error because column ID is of BIGINT and i can't convert `@ID` to INT pls how do i go about this? You there?

Comment: @NuruSalihu hope new edited answer provides necessary solution to your query

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from Student where Id='2'
union all
Select * from Student where Id='3'
union all
Select * from Student where Id='4'
```