# Splitting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a function like `SPLIT_PART` in SQL Server 2008 which divides a character string according to the specified separator and returns the nth part of the string?

For e.g

```
Jerry S/o Tom
```

|-----------------Name-----------------------------               |

| NIZAKAT ALI CHANNA S/O SHAMA NAZ ---|

| MUHAMMAD USAMAN  S/o  ABDUREHMAN |

**Desired Output**

| First Name------------------ | Last Name |

| NIZAKAT ALI CHANNA -- | SHAMA NAZ |

| MUHAMMAD USAMAN --- | ABDUREHMAN |

I want to get both Jerry and Tom separately saved in two columns

Comment: not out of the box - but if you google it, there are plenty of ready to use user defined functions that do what you are looking for.

Comment: look at this thread for example http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911167/split-function-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Please provide more sample data to make it easier to help you the problem. Do you have a sample schema (create table statements) to share as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a Field in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017176/splitting-a-field-in-sql)